# How can we change the target position of an arrow created using ArrowHelper

Tags: javascript, three.js

I mean can we modify the source or target positions?
var arrow = new THREE.ArrowHelper(direction.clone().normalize(), sourcePos, direction.length(), 0xff0000);

I know if we do ARROW.position.copy("some position"); then the whole arrow gets shifted but I want to change the source and not the target. Is there any way to achieve this?

Solution:
Use ARROW.setDirection(direction.clone().normalize());
    ARROW.setLength(direction.length());

always normalize the direction.

Comment: Look at `ArrowHelper.js` and you will see `.setDirection( dir )`. If you are still having problems, show your code and ask a specific question.

Comment: Thanks.It works. I used: ARROW.setDirection(direction.clone().normalize());
     ARROW.setLength(direction.length());